# Accessing array from a detail view controller into master view controller in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I've created my NSMutablearray in a detail view controller, assigned data etc but I'm just wondering how I can access that in the master view controller? This is my first time using table views etc, so I'm pretty clueless with it.

Thanks

Comment: If you're pretty clueless about table views, as you say, then read the Apple's "Table View Programming Guide for iOS". That will give you a good start.

Comment: You should definitely go through this pdf https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/RoadMapiOS.pdf it will definitely help u kick off your ios developing and it has an answer for your question too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways you can do this.

One of them is:
you set the `NSMutableArray` as a property on your view controller. Then, on your detail view controller you set a property for the view controller itself.

**ViewController interface**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *mutableArray;
```

**DetailViewController interface**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ViewController *viewController;
```

Then, on the ViewController, before pushing the DetailViewController, you set its `viewController` property to `self`

```
detailViewController.viewController = self;
```

Then, on the DetailViewController, you set the `viewController.mutableArray` property to the new array you just created.

You could do this on the `viewWillDisappear` method.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    self.viewController.mutableArray = _myNewlyCreatedMutableArray;
}
```

So, when you're back to the ViewController, just access `self.mutableArray` and you'll get the array you have created on the detail view.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the NSMutableArray to Viewcontroller using designated initializer.

Create Designated initiliazer in ViewController .m and delcare in .h.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil WithArr:(NSMutableArray*)arr
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
    self.arrTaskList=arr;
}
return self;
}
```

Like in DetailViewController when you create viewcontroller object

```
ViewController* vc=[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:@"" Arrr:self.arr];
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the pattern is the opposite, you create objects in the master view controller and pass a pointer to a specific item from this VC to the detail VC. However this is just the most common pattern, and what you´re doing can be right if you see it fit.

Usually, a Detail VC returns data to the Master VC through a **delegate**. There are hundreds of tutorials and questions here regarding how to do it, and I would en up copy-pasting a tutorial. But in short, the steps are:

1. you create a custom protocol, and declare a method that the Detail VC would call to pass any information to the Master VC
2. your Master VC implements or conforms to that protocol
3. your Detail VC has an instance variable of type `id<yourProtocol>` pointing to the delegate
4. The Master VC sets the delegate pointer in the Detail VC to self (to itself, e.g. the Master VC)

It sounds complicated, and it really is a little bit, but once you get the concept you'll find it useful in pretty much all your projects.

Another possibility is using **notifications** to let the Master VC know that something has changed in the Detail VC.