# How to pass data using didSelectRow in UISplitViewController - from master to detail

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I want to pass some core data from master to detail.

First the user selects a name which has a gender assigned. If gender Girl "pige" it goes to the girls UITableiew. From there each selection shows on detail view. 
I want to pass some data from the girl UITableiew. Like if its a girl color it pink. set a title etc.
So far i know how to pass around the UITableiew "master" but not how to get it to the detail view

Here's some code on how i manage the selection of UITableView etc.

**DetailViewContainerController**

```
 UIStoryboard* initial     = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-iPad" bundle:nil];
self.initital              = [initial instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"initialSite"];
[self addChildViewController:self.initital];
self.startSide              = [initial instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"startSide"];
[self addChildViewController:self.startSide];

-(void)initialSite:(int)viewId 
{
    UIViewController *viewController;
    switch (viewId) 
    {
        case 0:
            viewController = self.initital;
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
            break;
        case 1:
            viewController = self.startSide;
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
            break;
    }
    [self showChildViewController:viewController];
}

-(void)showChildViewController:(UIViewController*)content 
{
    if(topController != content) 
    {
        content.view.frame = [self.view frame]; // 2
        [self.view addSubview:content.view];
        [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
        topController = content;
    }
}
```

**startTableViewController**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad 
{
    arrayA = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[Start findAllSortedBy:@"navn" ascending:YES]] mutableCopy];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if ([[[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"gender"]isEqualToString:@"Pige"]) 
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-iPad" bundle:nil];
        DetailViewContainerController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuPige"];
        controller.forNavn = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }

    if ([[[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"gender"]isEqualToString:@"Dreng"]) 
    {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-iPad" bundle:nil];
        DetailViewContainerController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuDreng"];
        controller.forNavn = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
}
```

**MenuPige**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.detailViewContainerController initialSite:[indexPath row]];

if ([[[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"menuPunkt"]isEqualToString:@"Barnedåb / Navngiving"]) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"BarneDaab" bundle:nil];
    DetailViewContainerController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"barneDaab"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
```

in the girl menu.h i have the NSStrings of the data that i want to pass. So that is working. but how to get it to `detailviewcontroller` ?

**UPDATE:**
I tried this [Accessing array from a detail view controller into master view controller in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22677974/accessing-array-from-a-detail-view-controller-into-master-view-controller-in-obj/22678172#22678172)

but can't get it work

**UPDATE 2:**

```
    self.navigationController.parentViewController.navigationItem.title =     [self.detailViewContainerController.forNavn valueForKey:@"navn"];
doesn't work in the velkommen.m, it returns nil
```

**UPDATE 3:**

```
Leftmenucontroller.m - this works. but only to another uitableview. can't get it over to the detail view
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewContainerController *start = [[DetailViewContainerController alloc]init];
    start.forNavn = forNavn;
    NSLog(@"leftview = %@", forNavn);
    [self.detailViewContainerController initialSite:[indexPath row]];
}
```

**UPDATE 4:**

*startTableViewController.h*

```
{
    NSMutableArray      *arrayA;
    NSMutableArray      *tableData;
    NSString        *forNavn;
    NSString        *mellemNavn;
    NSString        *efterNavn;
    NSString        *gender;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString    *forNavn;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString        *mellemNavn;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString        *efterNavn;
@property (nonatomic, retain)   NSString        *gender;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray    *arrayA;
```

**UPDATE 6:**

I figured out that i can pass the data to `DetailviewContainerController` with this

```
    DetailViewContainerController *test = (DetailViewContainerController *)    [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
    test.leftViewController = self;
    test.forNavn = forNavn;
    NSLog(@"test = %@",test.forNavn);
```

but now i can't get it further from `DetailViewContainerController`. i tried this :

```
VelkommenViewController *test2 = (VelkommenViewController *)    [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
        test2.detailViewContainerController = self;
        test2.forNavn = self.forNavn;
        NSLog(@"test2 = %@",test.forNavn);
```

**Update 7:**

[image]

**Update 8:**

```
 VelkommenViewController *test2 = [[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject topViewController] childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
test2.forNavn = forNavn;
NSLog(@"test3 = %@",test2.forNavn);
```

Throws a error : -[UINavigationController setForNavn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x175b56c0

**Update 9:**

[image: new storyboard]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the receiving end this works:

```
    NSString *name = ((DetailViewContainerController *)self.parentViewController).forNavn;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you're doing, especially with the child view controller stuff. But, in general, when working with a split view controller, the detail controller can be accessed by using self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1] (if the detail controller is embedded in a navigation controller, then that gets you a reference to the navigation controller, and you have to use its topViewController property to get to the detail controller). You shouldn't be using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, or alloc init to access the detail controller, since either of those methods will give you a new instance  instead of referencing the one you have on screen.

Comment: i'm just trying to pass some data from the master view to the detail view. and i have no clue on if i should post a lot of code here to show what i'm doing or what.

Comment: from starttableviewcontroller to a childviewcontroller how would you pass data long there ?

Comment: @KennyVB, when passing data to another controller, the first thing you need to do is get a pointer to the controller you're trying to send data to. If that controller is a child, then you can use self.childViewControllers[0] (assuming there's only 1 child -- if there's more than 1, then that 0 might be some other number) to get a reference to the child.

Comment: hmm could you perhaps show me in code ? i don't quite understand what you mean by self.childViewController[0] ??
what does the number stand for and how do i use it to pass data ?

Comment: do i need to add forNavn to the childViewController ? if so where ?

Comment: @KennyVB, the number is a just the shorthand way to access a member of an array -- it's equivalent to [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0].

Comment: @KennyVB, I don't understand you last question. What is "forNavn"

Comment: it's a NSString which should contain my data i want to pass. Atleast i think it has the data i want to pass. i updated my code see above. please don't hesitate to ask for more code. i'll post it

Comment: i have a arrayA which is a nsmutablearray from that i fill forNavn with data that i need to pass.

Comment: @KennyVB, I'm having trouble understanding your controller structure. Do you have both a DetailViewContainerController, and a DetailViewController? I can't really give you more detailed advice without knowing your controller hierarchy.

Comment: @KennyVB, you still haven't explained your controller structure. If you could post a picture of your storyboard, that would be helpful. You're defining "test" two different times, once as a DetailViewContainerController, and once as a VelkommenViewController, but both times you define them as the same thing ([self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController) -- they both can't be that.

Comment: posted a screenshot of the first storyboard. i got multiple storyboard FYI

Comment: i have no idea what i'm doing with the pass data thingy. i'm just trying multiple ways which i have found via google and in here

Comment: @KennyVB, The only tricky part of passing data is to get a reference to the controller you're trying to send the data to. I can't read all the names of the controllers in your image, but it looks like the controller that says "Baby Bogen" and the other controller that's green at the bottom of the image are the ones you're adding as child view controllers of the  DetailViewContainerController. Is that true? If so, then self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject gets you to the navigation controller that DetailViewContainerController is embedded in. ... continued in the next comment.

Comment: @KennyVB, topViewController gets you to  DetailViewContainerController, and then you can use its childViewControllers property to get an array of its children. So something like this should get you to VelkommenViewController: VelkommenViewController *test2 = [[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject topViewController] childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]; You might need to add some casts to satisfy the compiler, and that 0 might need to be 1 depending on which of the children is VelkommenViewController. ... continued again

Comment: @KennyVB, you should also get rid of the 2 navigation controllers for the 2 child controllers -- the DetailViewContainerController is already embedded in a navigation controller, so the children don't need their own.

Comment: hmm but i have those to navigation controllers are "sub" menus when i click the first navigationcontroller it goes on to the next. is there a better way to build this ?

Comment: dident or won't work for me... throws this 
    -[UINavigationController setForNavn:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @KennyVB, I can't tell if there's a better way because I don't know what you want to do with them. You don't show any other controllers that you would push to with those navigation controllers (in fact you don't show any for the one that the DetailViewContainerController is in either). Your error is because you still have those navigation controllers -- if you keep them, then you have to use topViewController again to get to where you want to go.

Comment: when user click on the starttabelViewcontroller, the data is taking from core data after he/she has filled in a profile. then it takes the gender og goes to the right uinavigationcontroller according to what gender they choose when they made there profile.

Comment: @KennyVB, but none of that has anything to do with the navigation controllers you have on the two children -- unless for instance, you're going to push from VelkommenViewController to another controller that you don't have in your storyboard yet, they're unnecessary.

Comment: hmm.. how would you propose to make this work then ? i really appreciate the help also did you see the error it gave me ? aint there are way to fix this ?

Comment: @KennyVB, Yes I saw the error, and mentioned how to fix it in my second to last post -- you either need to get rid of those navigation controllers, or add topViewController to the end of that long definition of test2.

Comment: sorry for being so slow. Navigationcontroller ofc ! not the actual uitableview. i removed them but now i get a error -[DetailViewContainerController visibleViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: @KennyVB, which ones did you remove? All 3 of the ones on the large controllers (the detail controller side of the split view)?

Comment: removed the one from all 3 the details. the uitableview has one from standard i think. when you pull up the uisplitview from the toolbar

Comment: UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.visibleViewController;


think my error lies in here perhaps ? from my app delegate

Comment: @KennyVB, maybe. Update your post to show what your storyboard looks like now. Is DetailViewContainerController not embedded in a navigation controller any more -- I can't tell from what you said in your last comment.

Comment: there updated it. but i think my problem is how i set up the uisplitview in my app delegate ??

Comment: @KennyVB, yes -- since you no longer have the navigation controller, the split view's viewControllers.lastObject will be the DetailViewContainerController not a navigation controller. So you should have this: splitViewController.delegate = splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject

Comment: VelkommenViewController *test2 = [[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject topViewController] childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
has topviewcontroller in. how to remove it and make it work then ?

Comment: or is it my navigation that has the error ? 
 if ([[[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"gender"]isEqualToString:@"Pige"]) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-iPad" bundle:nil];
        DetailViewContainerController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuPige"];
        controller.forNavn = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        
        NSLog(@"pige = %@", controller.forNavn);
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
        }

Comment: @KennyVB, It's the same problem! You no longer have a navigation controller, so just remove the call to topViewController. VelkommenViewController *test2 = [[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject] childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: expected identifier it says when i just remove it

Comment: @KennyVB, There's too many brackets, it should be  VelkommenViewController *test2 = [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]

Comment: agh good, now it's working, how ever Velkommen still has null in forNavn. where should i place VelkommenViewController *test2 = [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    test2.forNavn = forNavn;
    NSLog(@"test3 = %@",test2.forNavn);

Comment: @KennyVB, Where do you have that code now? Do some logging to figure out why it's null. Is arrayA null where you have this code?

Comment: well i figured out that it goes from starttabelviewcontroller to lefttableviewcontroller to detailviewcontainercontroller and then it show velkommen. i placed the code in starttabelviewcontroller. in lefttableviewcontroller the data is still there but in detailviewcontainercontroller its not